# Corda recorded transaction mapping list size limitations

Tags: corda

As per [CordaRPCOps](https://docs.corda.net/api/javadoc/net/corda/core/messaging/CordaRPCOps.html#stateMachineRecordedTransactionMappingSnapshot--) documentation. **stateMachineRecordedTransactionMappingSnapshot** Returns a snapshot list of existing state machine id - recorded transaction hash mappings.

What is the size limit for this list? Is there any retention policy or timeframes?

Comment: I don't think they limit the size in the method stateMachineRecordedTransactionMappingSnapshot

Comment: @AkkapongKajornwongwattana does that mean that after 1kk+ transactions this list will return all of them?

Comment: I don't sure about that, If you have a lot of data you can get all of it?, But I think if you have a large of memory you can see all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit on the size of the list that the RPC functions returns. It will grow as the node has more and more transaction.